# Standardizing response variable in shrinkage/regularization

Tags: normalization, lasso, standardization, regularization

I know that I should [standardize my predictors](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/sardy/Papers/rescaling.pdf) before estimating something like `Lasso`. But what about the response variable? Do I standardise this as well?

Only concerned with impact on ability for the model to generalise out of sample.